# Creating objects and overriding their method constructors from java to kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, object, callable

```
PaintBuilder.newBuilder()
    .addString("Method: ", new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            return userMethod;
        }
    })
    .build()
```

So I have this code here in java and it has a method that accepts a string and a Callable, the code here is able to create a new object that isn't saved to any variable, basically just passing the new Callable object as a parameter. But it overrides of the methods after being created.

How do you do this with kotlin?

Callable... and then what? Doing brackets doesnt help, all it tells me is I cannot override call as its a local function.

I tried converting it to Kotlin by doing: Callable {...}

Comment: Is Callable a functional interface, non-functional interface, or class? A functional interface is one that has only one function declared that has no default implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the `Callable` you are referring to is [`java.util.concurrent.Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html), which is a functional interface (it has the `@FunctionalInterface` annotation). This means that you can pass a lambda directly, like so

```kotlin
PaintBuilder.newBuilder()
    .addString("Method: ", { userMethod })
    .build()
```

or, because the lambda is the last argument, even

```kotlin
PaintBuilder.newBuilder()
    .addString("Method: ") { userMethod }
    .build()
```

See the Kotlin documentation on [SAM conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) when the interface is in Java, or [functional interfaces](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html) for general information about Kotlin's functional interfaces.